# Testing Server for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and I would like to start coding and learning the language by building and running different simple pieces of code...

What would be the easiest way to get started and test ASP.NET code? I tried modifying the the httpd file in XAMPP to add asp support, which did not work. I am guessing using XAMPP to run ASP.NET is not the easy way to go about it.

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
     <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any advice,

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd look at the official [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/get-started) page for ASP.Net. You can use Cassini or IIS Express for actually testing your web applications. You'll want to upgrade to the full IIS for putting your web application in production.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft has put a lot of work into that - just skimming a few pages, seems like a great set of resources and tutorial.

Comment: Would I be able to use IIS Express to test web application, directly from my windows machine (without a windows server), is it like a testing environment?

Comment: @MiGusta yes. In Visual Studio 2012(Express, Pro, and other editions), they made this especially easy by making it the default(over the previous Cassini). Here's a tutorial to walk you through setting it up though if you need it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396569/Make-Web-Development-Easier-with-IIS-Express

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use IIS - I don't know if you can even use Apache for ASP.NET, but IIS is pretty much designed for it.

A basic hello-world page would need a little tweaking from your sample - once you have an application set up in IIS, this page should run:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
        <p>The time is <%= System.DateTime.Now %></p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

But this is not a good way to learn real ASP.NET stuff. You'll want to use Visual Studio for sure to learn, and run some tutorials online to get you started. I personally suggest starting with ASP.NET MVC, especially if you've already got any exposure to the MVC pattern. Classic ASP.NET WebForms have a lot of funky web voodoo, and might be a little tricky to learn if you are a web developer with other technologies.

You can get a free copy of Visual Studio - search for Visual Studio Express, and you'll find various free editions.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. I will go on and get a full copy Visual Studio through my college :) I have been coding PHP for the past 3 years so, I think its about time I pick up ASP.NET, for a competitive edge and personal interest, really.

Comment: You can use Apache for ASP.Net with Mono, but I second the recommendation for IIS.  It's definitely the easiest way to get started and you won't have the hassle of trying to translate tutorials from native .Net/VS/Windows to Mono/MonoDevelop/AltOS.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but don't I need to install the full version of IIS on a web server for me to be able to test web applications?

Comment: On a server, yes, you'll need IIS. When you're running locally with Visual Studio, as Earlz mentioned, you can run IIS Express or Cassini (IIS Express is better). But on a full server, you'll need to enable IIS. There's no additional cost or anything - just have to enable the feature on the Windows Features or Roles or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student then you can download it free from dreamspark.com just that you need to punch in some student id/university information.

Window default have an IIS server you just need to activate it from "Turn window features on off" but yea for hosting you need to have an IIS server.

Author Andy Olsen have nice tutorials/books online dedicated to asp.net, which are one of the best one's available.

I can check and get you the title of some of the best books (in case you want to proceed with that way).

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes if you can recommend a book, I would definitely be interested, and appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: I have few at my office, can't remember the Title, will go to work on Monday, will post it then.

Comment: Just to get your feet wet you can start from here (they have nice video tutorials) http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/asp-net/page/3/